# Indesign cs5.5 export as Epub interactive

Tags: adobe-indesign

i'm testing how far i can go with interactive epub format ebook.I've just added two buttons (prev and next) and 3 overlapping pictures to make a mini-slideshow. I've tested this on my pc with the preview panel and everything is working.
Whenever I try to export in epub format and open this book with calibre the slideshow is not working.

Any idea?

thanks
Luca

Answer (score 1):

This works in Preview and will work in the Content Viewer because at the moment it is supported only by the DPS plug-in.

The current ePub standard is v2, which doesn't support this kind of interactivity. Calibre currently adheres to the ePub 2.0 standard.

ePub 3.0 *will* support slideshows, videos, etc., when readers like Kindle, Nook, etc., support it. Apple hadn't announced that they would follow the ePub 3 standard, last I heard, but they are supporting a number of interactive features in the iBook format.

Comment: opening the book with my ipad shouldnt work? since it looks like ibooks app 'accepts epub 3.0'??..indesign is not using javascript for this purpose?